# How to sort ascending and descending order by vectors in C++

Tags: c++, sorting, vector

I am trying to write a C++ code of pancakes eater.I enter the number of pancakes that ate by 7 person. I found the max. and min. eater but I couldnt sort them by the number of pancakes that eaten by persons.Could any one help me please?

Thanks.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>

using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;
using std::vector;
using std::string;

struct Person
{
    string name;
    unsigned int pancakesAte;
};

int main()
{
    const int NUM_PEOPLE = 7;
    vector<Person> people;
    unsigned int mostPancakesIndex = 0;
    unsigned int leastPancakesIndex = 0;
    for(int index = 0; index < NUM_PEOPLE; index++)
    {
        std::stringstream ss;  
        Person person;  
        ss << "Person " << index; 
        person.name = ss.str();  
        cout << "how many did person " << person.name << " eat? ";
        cin >> person.pancakesAte;
        people.push_back(person);
        if ( person.pancakesAte > people[mostPancakesIndex].pancakesAte ){
            mostPancakesIndex = index;              }                     
            if ( person.pancakesAte < people[leastPancakesIndex].pancakesAte ){
            leastPancakesIndex = index; }
    }

    std::vector<Person>::iterator iter = people.begin();
    while (iter != people.end())
    {
        cout << iter->name << " ate " << iter->pancakesAte << " pancakes." << endl;
        ++iter;
    }
    cout << people[mostPancakesIndex].name << " ate the most pancakes - he/she ate " << people[mostPancakesIndex].pancakesAte << " pancakes." << endl;
    cout << people[leastPancakesIndex].name << " ate the least pancakes - he/she ate " << people[leastPancakesIndex].pancakesAte << " pancakes." << endl;
}**strong text**
```

**strong text**

Comment: You don't need a sort, and std::minmax_element should do what you need.

Comment: İf you run the code it prints how much pancakes eaten be each person but when I print them I want to sort them by pancakes number then Print all again.

Answer (score 1):

Last time I used `std::sort`, you could pass a comparison function to `std::sort`.  Thus if you wanted a descending sort, you pass a descending comparison function.  If you wanted to sort by even number of pancakes, you could write a function that did that.

The function is easy to write:

```
bool Comparison(const Type& a, const Type& b)
{
  // if you want a to come before b
  // in the ordering, return true.
  return // true or false
}
```

Sorting is invoked by:

```
std::sort(your_vector.begin(), your_vector.end(),
          Comparison); // Your ordering function.
```